# How to parse unicode String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I get Firebase realtime database value.

In dataSnapshot.value returns unicode if it is korean.

It looks like below

```
 This value is casted from ` as? String`
 Optional(" \"\\U3141\"")
```

`\u3131` is `ㅁ`, I have to show `ㅁ`

### how to parse this to utf8?

I developed using `Firebase RealTime Database` in `Android (Kotlin)`. But there is no problem like this.

Comment: let emoji = "\u{0003141}"

Comment: Thanks your comment. If I use the way, I tried to convert the `" \"\\U3141\""` to `"\u{0003141}"`. But I guess, there are some way `encode` `decode` way. So I hope to use that way If exist.